# Invalid column name ProveedoresID and UsuarioID on ASP.NET MVC 3 web app using Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am currently making a web app for MVC 3 using Entity Framework but I'm a beginner and I can't make the Code First mapping work properly and for some reason my Visual Studio doesn't have Database First and Model First functionality.
I have three model classes: Contacto, Proveedor and Usuario, each one of them corresponding to a table on an database existing database and I want to make those classes with Code First to map to this database. Contacto has a one-to-one relationship with Proveedor and Usuario. I declared the model classes like this:

```
public class Contacto 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }
    public Proveedor ProveedorID { get; set; }
    public Usuario UsuarioID { get; set; }
}

public class Proveedor 
{
    public short ID { get; set; }
    public string NombreProveedor {get;set;}
}

public class Usuario 
{
    public short ID { get; set; }
    public string NombreUsuario {get;set;}
}
```

The context class is the following:

```
 public class Contexto : DbContext 
{
    public DbSet<Contacto> Contactos { get; set; } 
 public DbSet<Proveedor> Proveedores { get; set; } 
 public DbSet<Usuarios> Usuarios { get; set; } 
}
```

I made a controller and view with CRUD methods but when the code gets to the EditorFor for the `Proveedor` attribute in `Contacto` I get a Invalid column name 'ProveedorID' and the same for UsuarioID. Changing the table names on the existing database doesn't fix this but sometimes makes the Invalid column name error refer to Contacto_ID instead of ProveedorID.
How do I make the reference to the Proveedor and Usuario model in Contacto work? And how override the automatic table mapping and specify the mapping manually? The name conventions don't work well in Spanish and don't detect properly that there is a relationship in a database.

Comment: What if you change `public Proveedor ProveedorID { get; set; }` to `public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }` and `public Usuario UsuarioID { get; set; }` to `public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't tell EF anything about how entities and properties map to table and column names, it will make its own assumptions by following a number of conventions. One of them is to assume that a foreign key column is the name of the referred entity with `_ID` appended to it.

If you don't want EF to follow these default conventions, you have to add your own mappings. I'll show an example of how you can do this.

First, I'd remove the "ID" part from the reference properties, and add primitive foreign key properties to the `Contacto` class:

```
public class Contacto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Telefono { get; set; }

    public short ProveedorID { get; set; }
    public Proveedor Proveedor { get; set; }

    public short UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

One way to tell EF about database names of entities and properties is fluent mapping. You can either do this in the `OnModelCreating` override of your context class, or in an `EntityTypeConfiguration` override:

```
public class ContactoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Contacto>
{
    public ContactoMap()
    {
        ToTable("tblContacto");
        Property(c => c.ProveedorID).HasColumnName("ProveedorId");
        HasRequired(x => x.Proveedor).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.ProveedorID);
        Property(c => c.UsuarioID).HasColumnName("UsuarioId");
        HasRequired(x => x.Usuario).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.UsuarioID);
    }
}
```

I just make up some names, since you don't mention which database names you want to have, but you get the idea.

The final step is to add this mapping to the model by overriding `OnModelCreating` in the context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ContactoMap());
}
```

By the way, if you have these properties like `ProveedorID`, EF will also infer these as foreign keys to the matching entity. Only when you don't include these primitive foreign key properties, EF will expect the column names with underscores in the database.